# Application windows change order when app switching

Tags: macos, big-sur, application-switcher

Has anyone else noticed this apparent bug in Big Sur (11.0.1)?

I've seen it now while using two different apps (Terminal and OmniOutliner). For example, I'm working in Terminal and I have two windows open - A and B. I have B on top and I switch to Safari to read something, then switch back to Terminal. Now window A is on top and hiding what I was doing in B. If I put B back on top, it just repeats again when I switch away from the app and come back again.

It happens if I switch apps with Command-Tab, or if I switch apps by manually clicking the dock.

Comment: Not that this really helps but I can't reproduce this issue, I don't have OmniOutliner but I tried with OmniFocus. Have you tried in safe mode in case it's another app you have running that's interfering?

Comment: No I haven't tried safe mode. And it's probably hard to reproduce. It wasn't doing it for a while, so I suspect if I reboot it will go away and then it takes some time to get messed up.

Comment: Ah sorry I read this like it always happened for you rather than only occasionally. While I have used Big Sur since beta 1 I'm a prolific user of full screen apps and tabs, so I never have two windows of the same application in the same space to have encountered this, though if the wrong window is getting focused I imagine my cmd-tab to switch space would switch to the wrong space if I had suffered from this.

Comment: Using tabs with OmniOutliner is a good workaround for me. I should be doing that anyway but I have old habits. With Terminal I have so many tabs it makes sense to group them in windows. I should also learn how to use full screen more, since I work on a small screen.

Comment: While I'm not going to tell you to change your workflow, I personally love the ‘Prefer tabs: always’ setting in System Preferences → General, it applies to any app and means tabs open instead of windows. Could be a workaround until Apple resolves the issue though?